# Many-to-many relationship in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many, dql

I have a `many-to-many` relationship. Entities are `Actor` and `Pys` (Films and TV shows). When I want the cast of film the relation works fine (returns all the actor and actress of a film) but the problem comes when I want to retrive all the films of an actor.

This is the relation in the phpmyadmin:

[image]

This is the error that appear:

`Key "actor" for array with keys "0" does not exist in ActorBundle:Default:actor.html.twig at line 3`

Here the necessary code:

Actor's `DefaultController`

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function peliculasAction($actId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $peliculas = $em->getRepository('ActorBundle:Actor')->findPeliculas($actId);

        return $this->render('ActorBundle:Default:actor.html.twig', array('peliculas' => $peliculas
                ));
    }
}
```

`ActorRepository`

```
class ActorRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findPeliculas($actId)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $consulta = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT p, d, a
            FROM ActorBundle:Actor a
            JOIN a.pys p JOIN p.director d
            WHERE a.actId = :actId
            ORDER BY p.pysAnyo DESC
        ');

        $consulta->setParameter('actId', $actId);

        return $consulta->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker')->getResult();
    }
}
```

`actor.html.twig`

```
(...)
{% block title %}{{ peliculas.actor.actNombre ~ ' ' ~ peliculas.actor.actApellidos }}{% endblock %}

{% block article %}
    <section class="article">
        <div id="datos-actor-director-genero">
            <strong>{{ 'Nombre:' | trans }} </strong>{{ peliculas.actor.actNombre ~ ' ' ~ peliculas.actor.actApellidos }}</br>
            <strong>{{ 'Fecha de nacimiento:' | trans }} </strong>{{ peliculas.actor.actFechaNacimiento | localizeddate('long', 'none') }}
        </div>
        <table>
            {% for pys in peliculas %}
                <tr id="fechaVotacion">
                    <td colspan="4">{{ pys.pysAnyo }}</td>
(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a doctrine collection from

```
$em->getRepository('ActorBundle:Actor')->findPeliculas($actId);
```

So in Twig, `peliculas` is a collection too, do a `for..in` or `peliculas[0]` if you only want the first element.

`peliculas` has no key `actor`, only numbres (0 : first actor, 1 : second actor, etc...)

Comment: Thanks you very much!! Finally I've corrected with a double `for..in` ;)